# Keyboard get automatically dismissed on iOS 11.2.6

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

When trying to type in a textfield after first character keyboard automatically gets dismissed, I have not implemented any textfield delegates, except `shouldChangeCharacterInRange` and in this method there is no `resignFirstResponder` or `endEditing` and there is not disabled textFields.

```
if ([theTextField isEqual:_userName]) {
        MAX_DIGITS = 15;
        NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
                return NO;
            } else {
                return [theTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string].length <= MAX_DIGITS;
            }
        }
    }

retutn YES:
```

Comment: Can you show `shouldChangeCharacterInRange`'s body?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code snippet.